# Render text align justify inside a div

Tags: html, css

I have this text Horseshoe Indianapolis inside the div element. "Indianapolis" starts from new line instead of that I do want it to start after the "Horseshoe" and whatever the remaining text to render in the second line. How do I achieve this with HTML and CSS?

[image]

```css
.box{
width:144px;
border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
Horseshoe Indianapolis
</div>
```

Comment: what has this to do with `text-align: justify`? What do you mean by remaining text? Is there actual text coming after that? Please post an actual code snippet that shows the issue

Comment: I post the actual code and someone understood and put the correct answer for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the property `word-break: break-all`

> Note: In contrast to word-break: break-word and overflow-wrap: break-word (see overflow-wrap), word-break: break-all will create a break at the exact place where text would otherwise overflow its container (even if putting an entire word on its own line would negate the need for a break).

[reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break#break-all)

```css
.box{
    width:144px;
    border:1px solid red;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    Horseshoe Indianapolis
</div>
```